# Using perl, how to convert sql block in logs to proper sql?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a hugh log file with sql debugs. I want to change them to proper sql.

For example in logs:

```
**** debug      Fri Aug 09 13:05:13 PDT 2013    1376078713845   /atg/web/viewmapping/ViewMappingRepository      executeUpdate2: [++SQLInsert++]
**** debug      Fri Aug 09 13:05:13 PDT 2013    1376078713845   /atg/web/viewmapping/ViewMappingRepository       INSERT INTO vmap_pv2pvad_rel(view_id,name,attr_id)
**** debug      Fri Aug 09 13:05:13 PDT 2013    1376078713845   /atg/web/viewmapping/ViewMappingRepository       VALUES(?,?,?)
**** debug      Fri Aug 09 13:05:13 PDT 2013    1376078713845   /atg/web/viewmapping/ViewMappingRepository      -- Parameters --
**** debug      Fri Aug 09 13:05:13 PDT 2013    1376078713845   /atg/web/viewmapping/ViewMappingRepository      p[1] = {pd} AmPvPuRoleAllMembers (java.lang.String)
**** debug      Fri Aug 09 13:05:13 PDT 2013    1376078713845   /atg/web/viewmapping/ViewMappingRepository      p[2] = {pd} synthCategoryDefinition (java.lang.String)
**** debug      Fri Aug 09 13:05:13 PDT 2013    1376078713845   /atg/web/viewmapping/ViewMappingRepository      p[3] = {pd: attributes} AmPvAttPuRolesMembersCatDef (atg.adapter.gsa.SingleValueGSAId)
**** debug      Fri Aug 09 13:05:13 PDT 2013    1376078713845   /atg/web/viewmapping/ViewMappingRepository      [--SQLInsert--]
```

With below perl code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FILE1, 'dps_ui_preview_view.log');
while (<FILE1>) {
   if (/\+\+SQL[Insert,Update]/../\-\-SQL[Insert,Update]/) {
    $_ =~ s/^.*\t//g;
    print $_;
   }
}

close(FILE1);
```

I am able to grab below sql format

```
[++SQLUpdate++]
 UPDATE vmap_im
    SET item_path=?
  WHERE id=?
-- Parameters --
p[1] = {pd: itemPath} /atg/userprofiling/ExternalProfileRepository (java.lang.String)
p[2] = {pd} AmImEuUsers (java.lang.String)
[--SQLUpdate--]

[++SQLInsert++]
 INSERT INTO vmap_fh(id,name,component_path)
 VALUES(?,?,?)
-- Parameters --
p[1] = {pd} AmFhPuFH (java.lang.String)
p[2] = {pd: name} External Preview Users formHandler (java.lang.String)
p[3] = {pd: path} /atg/remote/userprofiling/assetmanager/editor/service/PreviewUserAssetService (java.lang.String)
[--SQLInsert--]
```

I need to change above statements like below

```
UPDATE vmap_im SET item_path='/atg/userprofiling/ExternalProfileRepository' WHERE id='AmImEuUsers';
INSERT INTO vmap_fh(id,name,component_path) VALUES('AmFhPuFH','External Preview Users formHandler','/atg/remote/userprofiling/assetmanager/editor/service/PreviewUserAssetService')
```

Can anyone please let me know how can I achieve that? Any guide lines is much appreciated.

With help of regex grouping mentioned by user2676655
Here is the full code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $log;
my $match = 0;
my $q="";
my $p="";
open(FILE1, 'dps_ui_preview_view.log');
while (<FILE1>) {
   if (/\+\+SQL[Insert,Update]/../\-\-SQL[Insert,Update]/) {
      $_ =~ s/^.*\t//g;
      $log = $log . $_;
      if($_ =~ m/\-\-\]/) {
          ($q,$p) = ($log =~ /\+\+\](.*)-- Parameters --(.*)\[--/s);
          $p =~ s/^\s+//;
          my @params = split(/\n/,$p);
          foreach my $i (@params) {
            my ($val) = ($i =~ /\}(.*)\(/); 
            $val =~ s/^\s+//;
            $val =~ s/\s+$//;
            $q =~ s/\?/'$val'/;
          }
          $q =~ s/\n/ /g;
          $q =~ s/\s+/ /g;
          $q =~ s/ $/;/g;
          print $q,"\n";
          $log="";
       }
   }
} 
close(FILE1);
```

Comment: Are your paths you are trying to insert also in your log file?

Comment: From log file, I able to get the [++sql*] .. [--sql*] there will be update and insert statements, and param values can be paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$log = "[++SQLUpdate++]
UPDATE vmap_im
SET item_path=?
WHERE id=?
-- Parameters --
p[1] = {pd: itemPath} /atg/userprofiling/ExternalProfileRepository (java.lang.String)
p[2] = {pd} AmImEuUsers (java.lang.String)
[--SQLUpdate--]";


($q,$p) = ($log =~/\+\+\](.*)-- Parameters --(.*)\[--/s);

$p =~ s/^\s+//;
@params = split(/\n/, $p);

foreach (@params) {
  my ($val) = ($_ =~/\}(.*)\(/) ;
  $val =~ s/^\s+//;
  $val =~ s/\s+$//;

  $q =~s/\?/'$val'/;
}

$q =~s/\n/ /g;
$q =~s/\s+/ /g;
print $q;
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer, I am learning perl, regex grouping haven't came to my mind.